# Thunderbird Lightning: Customize colors and fonts of tasks list (userChrome.css)?

Tags: thunderbird, colors, tasks, lightning

To better organize my tasks I would like to customize my tasks list in Thunderbird Lightning:

- Color tasks according to category. Done by add-on Chromatask. Works fine.
- The tasks over the due date display in  **bold** (normally, in Thunderbird they become bright red [makes me nervous], if they do not belong to a category or do not change at all if they belong to a category - overruled by the add-on)
- Adapt selection colors to matching colors. When a task is selected by the mouse selected tasks display in blue; if the due date is over, the selection color changes to bright red. This color scheme is very difficult to match with my categories - looks terrible.

**How do I change to bold and different selection colors?**

For the email list I successfully changed the selection colors by changing the userChrome.css in ~/.thunderbird/--my-profile--.default/chrome:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

#threadTree treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected) {
background-color: #729fcf !important;
}

#threadTree treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(selected) {
color: #203e5f !important;
}

#folderTree treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected) {
background-color: #729fcf !important;
}
```

Many thanks for your help!

Thunderbird 52.7.0, Lightning 5.4.7, Platform Debian